# Is there any way to write a unit test for a function that uses scanf?

Tags: c, unit-testing, assert

I'm a computer science student, new to C and am trying to write a unit test for this program:

```
Board *get_board_sizes() {
    int row_count, column_count, mine_count = 0;
    Board *struct_to_return = (Board *)calloc(1, sizeof(Board));
    int rerun = 0;
    do {
        if (rerun == 1) {
            printf("Incorrect size");
        }
        rerun = 1;
        printf("Choose how many rows, columns, and mines you would like\n");
        printf("Note that maximum number of rows anc columns are 30 and maximum number of mines are rows*columns\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &row_count, &column_count, &mine_count);
        while (getchar() != '\n');
    } while ((row_count > 30 || row_count < 1) || (column_count > 30 || column_count < 1) || (mine_count < 1 || mine_count >= (row_count * column_count)));
    //while(getchar() != '\n');
    struct_to_return->row_count = row_count;
    struct_to_return->column_count = column_count;
    struct_to_return->mine_count = mine_count;
    return struct_to_return;
}
```

My question is is there any way to test the `scanf` function? My thoughts were I could maybe save the numbers it should scan into a file and try to get it from there but I'm struggling to fit it into the unit test.

I was thinking of doing it like this:

```
TEST get_fitting_number_from_players() {
    char file[] = "tests/board_size/fitting_number";
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    Board *size = get_board_sizes(fp);
    ASSERT(/*havent added yet*/);
}
```

But I don't see the get_board_sizes function being able to get the numbers from the file. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `fscanf` takes a filepointer as first param. use `stdin` to mimic `scanf`

Comment: Aside: before you even do unit testing, you should check the return value from `scanf`, and the `getchar()` kludges show a lack of understanding of how `scanf` handles whitespace.

Comment: Since you're doing `while (getchar() != '\n');` to get rid of the newline, your data is _line_ oriented with 3 numbers per line. You might be better off using `fgets` to get a line and then `sscanf` to parse the line. If you do that, using `fgets` with `strtol` would be better as it allows for exact syntax checking of the input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to test the `scanf` function?

Yes indeed, you can start by testing the return value: it must be 3 if all 3 numbers have been read from the user.

There are more issues in the function:

- you do not check for `calloc()` failure.
- you do not check the return value of `scanf()`: you have undefined behavior on invalid input.
- the loop `while (getchar() != '\n');` will never stop once you reach the end of file.
- instead of cramming all value tests in the `while` clause of a `do` / `while` loop, use a `for(;;)` (aka *for ever loop*) and explicit tests with meaningful error messages.

Here is a modified version:

```
Board *get_board_sizes(void) {
    for (;;) {
        int c, count, row_count, column_count, mine_count;

        printf("Choose how many rows, columns, and mines you would like\n"
               "Note that the maximum number of rows and columns is 30\n"
               "and the maximum number of mines is rows*columns\n");
        // read user input
        count = scanf("%d %d %d", &row_count, &column_count, &mine_count);
        // discard the rest of the input line
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;

        // check input validity
        if (count != 3) {
            printf("invalid input.\n");
        } else
        if (row_count < 1 || row_count > 30)
        ||  column_count < 1 || column_count > 30) {
            printf("invalid dimensions\n");
        } else
        if (mine_count < 1 || mine_count >= row_count * column_count) {
            printf("invalid number of mines\n");
        } else {
            // input is valid: allocate the board, initialize it and return it
            Board *board = (Board *)calloc(1, sizeof(*board));
            if (board == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "allocation failure\n");
                return NULL;
            }
            board->row_count = row_count;
            board->column_count = column_count;
            board->mine_count = mine_count;
            return board;
        }
        // keep asking the user unless at end of file
        if (c == EOF) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected end of file\n");
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding the unit test: you can redirect standard input from a file using `freopen()`:

```
TEST get_fitting_number_from_players() {
    char file[] = "tests/board_size/fitting_number";
    freopen(file, "r", stdin);
    Board *size = get_board_sizes();
    ASSERT(/*havent added yet*/);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to write a unit test for a function that uses scanf?

Yes.
Use `freopen(..., "r", stdin)` to redirect reading from `stdin` to a file of your choosing.  Fill that file with the data you want `scanf(), getchar()`, etc. to receive and then call you test code.

```
int test(size_t isz, const char *in) {
  const char *tmp = "t.txt";
  FILE *outf = fopen(tmp, "w");
  if (outf == NULL)
    return 1;
  if (fwrite(in, sizeof in[0], isz, outf) != isz)
    return 2;
  fclose(outf);
  if (freopen(tmp, "r", stdin) == NULL) {
    return 3;
  }

  // Perform your unit test.
  Board *size = get_board_sizes(fp);
  ASSERT(/*haven't added yet*/);
  return 0;
}

const char *data = "1 2 3\nNext line\n...\n";
if (test(strlen(data), data) == 0) {
  puts("Success");
} else {
  puts("Fail");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to unit test your `get_board_sizes` function is to modify the function so that it takes an additional parameter that provides the input, rather than hardcoding it to read from *stdin*. Something like:

```c
Board *get_board_sizes(FILE *in) {
    /* ... */
    fscanf(in, "%d %d %d", &row_count, &column_count, &mine_count);
    /* ... */
}
```

Then in your unit test you can synthesize an input for the function. Using [cgreen](https://github.com/cgreen-devs/cgreen) for unit tests, I wrote the following test. In this code:

1. We create temporary file to act as the input to the `get_board_sizes` function.
2. We populate the temporary file with our sample input
3. We rewind the file.
4. We pass the file as the input parameter to `get_board_sizes`
5. Finally, we verify that we get back the expected response

```
Ensure(GetBoard, parse_input) {
  char tempname[20];
  int fd;
  FILE *test_stdin;
  Board *board;

  sprintf(tempname, "stdinXXXXXX");
  fd = mkstemp(tempname);
  unlink(tempname);

  assert_that(fd, is_greater_than(-1));
  test_stdin = fdopen(fd, "r+");
  assert_that(test_stdin, is_not_null);

  fputs("10 15 5\n", test_stdin);
  fseek(test_stdin, 0, SEEK_SET);

  board = get_board_sizes(test_stdin);
  assert_that(board->row_count, is_equal_to(10));
  assert_that(board->column_count, is_equal_to(15));
  assert_that(board->mine_count, is_equal_to(5));
}
```

Even if you're using a different unit testing framework the general idea is the same.

---

In your actual (non-test) code, you would call `get_board_sizes(stdin)` instead of simply calling `get_board_sizes()`.

---

You may need to think about other ways to restructure `get_board_sizes` to write tests for invalid inputs.

Comment: Passing the input stream is not needed, you can use `freopen()` to redirect standard input from a file.

Comment: That is also a good option!